# How to upload an audio .mp3 or .wav file using Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I want to upload an audio file on Facebook using my windows phone 7 application.
I tried to upload with Facebook graph API but it returns me an unsupported request error.
Can any one provide any example or suggest solutions to this problem.

Thank you